# password set during checkout issue

Tags: magento, passwords, account

I have an issue with customer registered through checkout.

After the checkout process, the customer lands in “My Account” but once logged off, he can’t acces "My Account" anymore, the message "Invalid login or password" is displayed.

Setting a new password through “Forgotten Password” button seems to solve the problem for the customer. (But it would be great if the password could work directly without passing through this step.)

I think (but am not sure at all) that the password set through billing.phtml is not stored correctly.

The customers registered through "Register" button are saved correctly and don't encounter any issue.

I have in template/persistent/Customer/form/register.phtml:

```
            <li class="fields">
                <div class="field">
                    <label for="password" class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo $this->__('Password') ?></label>
                    <div class="input-box">
                        <input type="password" name="password" id="password" title="<?php echo $this->quoteEscape($this->__('Password')) ?>" class="input-text required-entry validate-password" />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="field">
                    <label for="confirmation" class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo $this->__('Confirm Password') ?></label>
                    <div class="input-box">
                        <input type="password" name="confirmation" title="<?php echo $this->quoteEscape($this->__('Confirm Password')) ?>" id="confirmation" class="input-text required-entry validate-cpassword" />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </li>
```

In template/Customer/form/resetforgottenpassword.phtml:

```
        <li class="fields">
            <div class="field">
                <label for="password" class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo $this->__('New Password'); ?></label>
                <div class="input-box">
                    <input type="password" class="input-text required-entry validate-password" name="password" id="password" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="field">
                <label for="confirmation" class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo $this->__('Confirm New Password'); ?></label>
                <div class="input-box">
                    <input type="password" class="input-text required-entry validate-cpassword" name="confirmation" id="confirmation" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>
```

And in template/persistent/checkout/onepage/billing.phtml, which I think is the culprit:

```
            <li class="fields" id="register-customer-password">
                <div class="field">
                    <label for="billing:customer_password" class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo $this->__('Password') ?></label>
                    <div class="input-box">
                        <input type="password" name="billing[customer_password]" id="billing:customer_password" title="<?php echo $this->quoteEscape($this->__('Password')) ?>" class="input-text required-entry validate-password" />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="field">
                    <label for="billing:confirm_password" class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo $this->__('Confirm Password') ?></label>
                    <div class="input-box">
                        <input type="password" name="billing[confirm_password]" title="<?php echo $this->quoteEscape($this->__('Confirm Password')) ?>" id="billing:confirm_password" class="input-text required-entry validate-cpassword" />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </li>
```

I tried several modifications to billing.phtml, such as:

```
<label for="password" class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo $this->__('Password') ?></label>
<input type="password" name="password" id="password" title="<?php echo $this->quoteEscape($this->__('Password')) ?>" class="input-text required-entry validate-password" />
<input type="password" name="password" title="<?php echo $this->quoteEscape($this->__('Confirm Password')) ?>" id="confirmation" class="input-text required-entry validate-cpassword" />
```

But I’m still leading to the same result.
I’m on a CE 1.9.3.1 patched with SUPEE 9652.

How to make Customer registered during checkout being saved correctly?

Comment: Is this question poorly formulated or is there missing informations?
Anyone else facing this problem?

Comment: check your logs and check for email verification too.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. Nothing is displayed in the system.log or exception.log. About email verification, could you specify? As the same Template is used for both Customer new account confirmation. Once displaying the password (Customer set through registration) and once displaying nothing (Customer registered through checkout).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have 4 errors concerning lib/Varien/Crypt/Mcrypt.php

```
Warning: mcrypt_generic_init(): Key size is 0 in /lib/Varien/Crypt/Mcrypt.php on line 94
Warning: mcrypt_generic_init(): Key length incorrect  in /lib/Varien/Crypt/Mcrypt.php on line 94
Warning: mcrypt_generic_deinit(): 495 is not a valid MCrypt resource  in /lib/Varien/Crypt/Mcrypt.php on line 135
Warning: mcrypt_module_close(): 495 is not a valid MCrypt resource  in /lib/Varien/Crypt/Mcrypt.php on line 136
```

I thought it was relative to a module is missing in PHP Mcrypt on my server (https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/35888). But it's not the case as by installing a fresh CE 1.9.3.1 in a folder in the root of the same Magento installation is doing its job properly with the same server configuration and Mcrypt.php. Moreover, the password set during registration with form (?and using the same encryption?), is set properly.

I'll open a new post with more precisions.

@urfusion, thank you for advice, I was looking at the wrong end of system.log (thought it was writing on the top...)

**Edit**

I got it, the solution's here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/42474835/7553582